# get wait cursor for whole java application

Tags: java

I have a java application with swing incorporation. There are several complex component hierarchy, where you click one button which opens a dialog box and then in that dialog box, if you click one button it opens another one( either result window or something else). Usually these are running in thread. When they run, I want to have cursor sign change to "wait" for the whole application, but its not happening when I am on top of multiple dialog boxes. It happens only if I am at the application level, root level. I am using following code

```
// start wait cursor on menu bar
    RootPaneContainer root = ((RootPaneContainer) mMenuBar.getTopLevelAncestor());
    root.getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    root.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {});
    root.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

    // start wait cursor on main window
    root = ((RootPaneContainer) mMainPanel.getTopLevelAncestor());
    root.getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    root.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {});
    root.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Start wait cursor.");
```

I got above code from [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue065.html)

Comment: Dialogs are separate window components detached from windows peer, so glass pane will not work. I would rather ask how do you create your dialogs?

Comment: I am using JDialog ,etc to create them. Is that what you asked?

Comment: but with or without parent window?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not that expert. How would I know that. Though while creating the JDialog, I dont see any involvement of parent window to it.